# Direct access slower than using functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I was conducting some performance testing and have discovered something quite strange. I have set up a short script to time how long it takes to perform certain actions.

```
declare @date date
declare @someint int
declare @start datetime
declare @ended datetime
set @date = GETDATE()

DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = 0

set @start = GETDATE()

WHILE (@count < 1000)
BEGIN

--Insert test script here 

END

set @ended = GETDATE()

select DATEDIFF( MILLISECOND, @start, @ended)
```

The table I was running tests againsts contains 3 columns, `MDay`, and `CalDate`. Every calendar date has a corresponding M(Manufacturing)Day. The table may look something like this:

```
MDay  |  CalDate
  1   | 1970-01-01
  2   | 1970-01-02
```

I wanted to test how efficient one of our functions was. This function simply takes in a `date` and returns the `int MDay` value. I used direct access, basically the same thing without the function, and tests resulted in this method take **twice** as long! Code I inserted into the loop is provided below. I used a random date in an attempt to eliminate caching (if exist).

Function

```
select @someint = Reference.GetMDay(DATEADD( D, convert(int, RAND() * 1000) , @date))
```

Definition for above

```
create Function [Reference].[GetMDay]
    (@pCaLDate smalldatetime
    )
    Returns int
as

Begin
Declare @Mday  int

Select @Mday = Mday 
from Reference.MDay
where Caldate = @pCaLDate
```

Direct

```
select @someint = MDay from Reference.MDay where CalDate = DATEADD( D, convert(int, RAND() * 1000) , @date)
```

I even tried using a static `@date` for my direct code and the difference in times are negligible, so I know the `convert` call isn't holding it back.
What the heck is going on here?

Comment: Sorry, I know why the result differs, but I deleted the answer because Martin Smith downvoted it and says that it's nonsense.

Comment: @Guffa - It was nonsense. Your inability to find any documentation to back up your theory shows this.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I didn't see you showing any documentation either. What are you doing, and who do you think that it gains?

Comment: @Guffa - What documentation do you expect? There won't be any that states specifically that a non existent feature doesn't exist. As for what I'm doing, Firstly correcting mis information that people might believe as it comes from a high rep user and secondly responding to your comment above.

Comment: @Jeff - Which did you try first? Also did you try running this test more than once? Maybe the first run brought data pages into cache that benefited subsequent runs or maybe it was just due to transient conditions on the server

Comment: @MartinSmith: Yes, that is what you think that you do, but that doesn't make it true. What you are actually doing is keeping people from helping other people.

Comment: @Guffa - Incorrect Answers are more of a hinderance than a help. SQL Server does not automatically memoize the result of scalar UDF calls into some cache of previous results as your answer claimed.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Do you have any documentation to back up your claim? No? Ok, then what you are saying is nonsense.

Comment: @MartinSmith I ran the `function` method first. If results were cached, the `direct` method should have been faster

Comment: @Jeff: The direct query can't be cached, because it contains the random calculation.

Comment: @Guffa Am I to take it from the comment above that you believe the result would be cached for the direct query but for that? The only thing cached in SQL Server relevant to this discussion is pages in the buffer pool and execution plans. Results aren't cached. Maybe you are getting confused with MySQL's query cache. Perhaps you should ask a question on the site about this as you seem to have a few misconceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx is the execution plan the same on your sql server for both methods?

Comment: I've never used this tool. Seems interesting. Both execution plans are really similar in that the cost to query the table is 97% of the work. There is green text that states `Missing Index (Impact 94.3642): Create Nonclustered Index[<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>] ON [Reference].[MDay](CalDate)`. What does it all mean?

Comment: @Jeff: It means that the query planner sees that the query would very likely run significantly faster if you added the index.

Comment: I've created another table that includes a proper index and changes are negligible. The suggestion posted above is no longer there.